# How do I programmatically update an existing submitted webform submission in Drupal?

Tags: 7, rules, webforms

I am attempting to use PHP in Drupal rules to update the values in submitted webform submissions. I can access and view the data correctly. When I assign a new value to a field it will even show up correctly if I use print $submission->data[61][0]; But when I navigate to the submission results page the field hasn't been updated.

I have tried using the webform_submission_update() function to push my change but still no luck.

**Question:** How do I programmatically update an existing submitted webform submission in Drupal?

**Code:**

```
$submission = webform_menu_submission_load($nid, $sid);

// Two ways I've tried to update the data
$submission->data[61][0] = "testwork";
$submission->data[61]['value'][0] = 'Declined';

// If I do print $submission->data[61][0]; it will show the new value.

webform_submission_update($nid, $submission);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do that:

```
// Load the webform submissions file. The webform_get_submission() and
// webform_submission_update() functions are located here.
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');

// Load the node and submission.
$node = node_load(YOUR_NODE_ID);
$submission = webform_get_submission($node->nid, YOUR_SUBMISSION_ID);

// Change submission data.
//
// To see what's available, install Devel and run dpm($submission);
$submission->data[YOUR_FORM_ELEMENT_ID][0] = 'Update';

// Finally, update the submission.
webform_submission_update($node, $submission);
```

Documentation:

- [`webform_get_submission()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submission/7)
- [`webform_submission_update()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21includes%21webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_submission_update/7)