# Communication between hook_webform_submission_presave and a Custom submit function

Tags: forms, webforms

My users fill out a registration form (with their emails, and some options). I calculate with ajax from these options a price. I want to redirect them to an other site, so they can pay there the price.

With `form_alter` I add some hidden fields (components) to my webform (like `PaymentRequestId` and Payment Status). And I set a **custom submit function** to the form, as I want to redirect the users.

But I have some difficulties: first I tried to generate and set the `PaymentRequestId` in my **custom submit function**, but I was not able to save the value into the formfield of the submission there. I already asked it [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247071/set-the-value-of-a-hidden-form-component), how to do that, but I could not achieve it. So for a suggestion, I moved these into a `hook_webform_submission_presave` function.
Now, I was able to save my `PaymentRequestId` (HURRAY!).

But I also need this ID in my **custom submit function**, as the URL (where I need to redirect my users) is generated from this.
But neither the `$form`, nor the `$form_state` in my **custom submit function** does not contains the value of the `PaymentRequestId`. I do not understand why, as when I watch the Submission on the admin interface, the `PaymentRequestId` is there.

Do you have any ideas/workarounds for my problem? Thanks a lot, for all your efforts!

Comment: Do you use ajax to submit your form? If so, then you might need to redirect the user in a custom ajax submit callback.

Comment: @Ismini: no, I do not use ajax to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way with the `hook_webform_submission_presave` function, but finally I found a solution with the help of [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191877/79408) answer to an other question, to save values into the webform submission in `my_custom_submit` function.  Here is the part of my code from `my_custom_submit` function, which updates hidden field:

```
<?php
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
$node = node_load($form_state['storage']['details']['nid']);
$submission = webform_get_submission($node->nid, $form_state['storage']['details']['sid']);
foreach ($form['#node']->webform['components'] as $key => $component) {
  if ( $component['form_key'] == 'my_unique_id' ){
    $submission->data[$key][0] = $my_uniqe_key;
  }
}
webform_submission_update($node, $submission);
```

I tried all your suggestions, but non of them worked for me. Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that your ajax return your results to the form so as you can have the value on your custom form submit. Maybe one more hidden field with the new value would be the solution. So in your custom ajax callback you need to `return $form['new_value_field'];`

After that, in your custom submit function you should get the new value and you can save your form in there. `$form_state->setValue('new_field', 'new_value');`. Even though I'm not sure if you need to set the value again as you already did it with ajax earlier.

Finally, you can redirect the user in your custom submit function by using `$form_state->setRedirect('machine_name');`

Comment: Sorry @Ismini, but you misunderstood my question. Most of what you explain was already working. The missing part was to set the value. To your suggestion (`$form_state->setValue`) I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on array`  error message.